# Name of variable assigned in .NET

Tags: vb.net, class, reflection

VB2010. Not even sure if this is possible but for debugging purposes I want to print out the name of the variable that was assigned to a master variable (both being classes).

```
        Dim mstTripClass As Trip = Nothing
        Select Case sc
            Case "0"
                mstTripClass = driver.BusinessTrip
            Case "7", "8"
                mstTripClass  = driver.LeisureTrip
            Case "10"
                mstTripClass = driver.OtherTrip
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("Invalid trip class")
        End Select

        Debug.Print("Trip class=" & mstTripClass.GetType.ToString)
```

This prints out

```
        Trip class=MyCompany.MyDept.MyApp.Trip
```

What i would like to print out is something like:

```
        Trip class=BusinessTrip
```

I'm not even sure how to search for this type of thing. I searched for reflection but came up empty.

Comment: Just print out sc, the number will tell you the source. Or add a debug print inside each case. It also depends on the type of each of your variable, is BusinessTrip an instance of Trip? You Trip class could have a TripType that indicate if it's a Business/Leisure/Other

Comment: Yes all BizTrip, LeusureTrip, OtherTrip are Trip types. That's why I can assign them to a master variable of type Trip. Since the variable already denotes what type it is I was hoping there was a way to do this without adding another field.

Comment: You can't figure out where the variable was copied from unless you keep that information somewhere. What you can do is add a property to your Trip class indicating what type of trip it is. This makes perfect sense since this is logic that should be part of the Trip class. Then you only need to do Debug.Print("Trip class=" & mstTripClass.TypeOfTrip)

Comment: Also, your Select Case should actually be in the driver class. Since this seems like logic about the driver (sc doesn't tell me much about what that variable is and with those magic numbers). You would have. mstTripClass = driver.GetTrip(sc)

Comment: I ended up just adding a description field to the class and that will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No reflection needed here at all. Two easy alternatives come to mind:

1. Turn `driver` into an `Enum` having the values `BusinessTrip`, `LeisureTrip` etc.
2. Whatever type `driver.BusinessTrip` has, extend that type with a abstract string property `TypeDescription` and have the `BusinessTrip`, `LeisureTrip` etc. subtypes override the property so that they return a textual description.

Comment: Another option: override `ToString` in `Trip`

Comment: the driver class is a much bigger class where the three trip types are defined so cant turn it into an emum. As above I could ad another field but since the variable name already denotes what type of Trip it is i was hoping I could do it without adding yet another field. Not sure how I can override ToString to give me the variable name. That's essentially what I'm trying to do but what functionality do i use?